# Receive multiple console inputs in Java

Tags: java, input, console

In C++, when we need to receive multiple console inputs (all keyed within the same line), we use the following:

```
int num1, num2, num3;
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

//Input
21 33 42[Enter]

//Output
21 33 42
```

To do the same thing in Java, is this the proper way to do it?

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int num1, num2, num3;
num1 = scn.nextInt();
num2 = scn.nextInt();
num3 = scn.nextInt();
```

Comment: I think your solution is a decent way

Comment: yes solution is proper.

Comment: So you answered your own question. You can combine declaration and assignment (`int num1 = scn.nextInt();`), but I bet you know already...

Comment: So I guess I am doing right as above. Thanks all for your comments. I was asking because I didn't get a chance to learn Java starting from the foundation in school. I can code in Java, but still unsure whether I am doing things in the proper way.

Comment: Try it. It will work or not work.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, but be careful if you have to read string using .nextLine() just after reading the integer values, if you hit "enter" after the integer, the nextInt() would consume only the integer value and ignore the carriage return, which will be consumed by the .nextLine() if you are trying to read a string immediately after. Just add an extra .nextLine() after the .nextInt() in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want read an unknown amount if inputs, try this:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String s = "";
while (!(s = scn.next()).equals("stop")) {
    try {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("Thats not a Number!!");
    }
}
```